# Interpretation of Graph about Random Forest (#Randomly selected Predictors/ Accuracy)

Tags: r, data-visualization, cross-validation, random-forest, overfitting

Here i am attaching plot of random-forest in R please help me to interpret.

Why does this graph have a negative slope?
[image: result of random forest classificatio]

Comment: You see the effect ov overfitting.  Search this site, a lot of posts about overfitting.

Comment: See  http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+overfitting++random-forest

Answer (score 1):

From the plot, it seems you choose 2, 6 and 10 random selected features with cross validation.

Good result for you, it's not the more features, the better prediction result for random forest.

For random forest, the optimal number of features is the sqrt of features numbers, but you can tuning it with cross validation. The best feature numbers seems is 6 for you (maybe 5 or 7, you can try again).

The more features, the more redundancy features being selected as split nodes, so it's true for the decrease of predictions.